# find elements in one tuple but not in the other tuple in Hadoop Pig

Tags: hadoop, join, apache-pig

I have two tuples (of strings, and big -- each are of a few million strings) and I want to find elements in one tuple but not in the other tuple in Hadoop Pig. Wondering if good code reference?

Sample input,

```
tuple 1: (Hello, World, Hadoop, Pig, Stackoverflow)
tuple 2: (Hello, World, Hadoop, Spark, Python)
```

Sample output,

```
(Pig, Stackoverflow)
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Can you add sample input and expected output to the question ?

Comment: Sure, added. Thanks @MuraliRao for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this could be to turn that tuple into a bag of tuples with each string being a standalone tuple. Then you can use the set difference operation at http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/guide/set-operations.html to find the strings that are in one set but not the other.

Comment: any thoughts how to "turn that tuple into a bag of tuples"? :)